# Configure sflow form HP A5500-24G-4SFP HI to reach ManageEngine Network Analyzer

Tags: networking, hp, switch

I Just inherited an old windows server with windows 2008 and ManageEngine Network Analyzer, in this network I have an Hp switch.

The switch is a HP A5500-24G-4SFP HI.

How can I collect and send sFlow from the switch to ManageEngine.

I've been reading the manual that can be found here.

https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docLocale=en_US&docId=emr_na-a00040098en_us

The chapter about configuration of sFlow data is not helping me.
I don't understand the agent - collector description.
Perhaps the agent should be an ip on the switch and the collector the ip of manage engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetFlow Analyzer will auto discover the device once the flow reaches the server over the UDP port 9996.

below sflow configuration for HP A5500 series switch

```
system-view
sflow agent ip <Device IP>
sflow collector 1 ip <NetFlow Installed IP> port 9996
```

Follow this steps for all interfaces

```
interface <Interface name>
sflow counter interface 60
sflow counter collector 1
sflow sampling-rate 1000
```